# How to find the data validation source from excel 2010

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, vba

I have an excel template which is having lots of data validations and I need to convert the data validation function into a c# code.

I'm unable to find the cell range from where the values of data validation is set.
The data validation is adjusting its size as per cells size adjustment.

Any guess? I searched a lot in the web but could not find a proper solution for this.

Comment: There are two types of comboboxes that you can use on an Excel worksheet - Form combobox or ActiveX combobox. The properties differ between the two. Which type is being used on your spreadsheet?

Comment: Thanks Robin Mackenzie! I

Comment: I found that this is not a combo box, it is a data list. Data menu -> Data validation. I hope this control has no cell link property like combo box, this is just for selecting values for the current cell.

Answer (score 2):

If a cell - say `Sheet1!A1` has a data validation, then to retrieve the range that is providing the values for the data validation you use the following in VBA:

```
Sheet1.Range("A1").Validation.Formula1
```

With Excel Interop you can do this in C# (untested):

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range xlRange;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Validation xlValidation;
string validationSource;

// Set Sheet 1 as the sheet you want to work with
xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

// get range
xlRange = xlWorkSheet.get_Range("A1", System.Reflection.Missing.Value);

// get validation object
xlValidation = xlRange.Validation;

// get source
validationSource = (string)xlValidation.Formula1;
```

See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.validation_members.aspx).

HTH